# Как исправить ошибку C1033 в Visual C++ Express?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, c++

Как исправить ошибку C1033 в Visual C++ Express?

Answer (score 2):

[Здесь](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/Vsexpressvc/thread/c18f09f2-871e-4810-a803-c889994415c3) пишут, что такая ошибка возникает, если используется Win7 и старые версии студии (старые по мнению Майкрософта, к примеру 2005).
Решений две - использовать правильную версию студии, рекомендованную Майкрософт (видимо последнюю) или запускать студию в режиме эмуляции XP.

Comment: Спасибо, запустил от имени админа, и все заработало